# Mobile Chrome Apps: cca checkenv shows no output

Tags: android, node.js, ubuntu, ant

I have setup the installation process found on https://github.com/MobileChromeApps/mobile-chrome-apps/blob/master/docs/Installation.md on 2 different linux environments without problem and the same could be said for my current environment until 2 days ago. 
Everything on that install for a linux environment is there, was able to run cca prepare android and see my application on my android phone. I dont know what changed but no cca command returns any output. 
A whereis cca outputs cca: /usr/local/bin/cca however cca commands returns no response. Any idea or log which i should tail?

Answer (score 0):

Since this doesn't provide any answer, and it seems people are still coming to see this question, I will share my experience related to that problem.

In my case I am trying that on a Ubuntu system (14.04 to be precise).
on my machine I have two packages that one might confuse :

```
Package: node
Priority: optional
Section: universe/hamradio
Conflicts: nodejs-legacy
Description-en: Amateur Packet Radio Node program (transitional package)
 The existing node package has been renamed to ax25-node. This transitional
 package exists to ease the upgrade path for existing users.
```

and

```
Package: nodejs
Priority: extra
Section: universe/web
Description-en: evented I/O for V8 javascript
 Node.js is a platform built on Chrome's JavaScript runtime for easily
 building fast, scalable network applications. Node.js uses an
 event-driven, non-blocking I/O model that makes it lightweight and
 efficient, perfect for data-intensive real-time applications that run
 across distributed devices.
 .
 Node.js is bundled with several useful libraries to handle server
 tasks:
 .
 System, Events, Standard I/O, Modules, Timers, Child Processes, POSIX,
 HTTP, Multipart Parsing, TCP, DNS, Assert, Path, URL, Query Strings.
```

So first make sure you don't mistake one for the other.

Secondly you will need nodejs-legacy to have the node executable ( and not nodejs ).

Once I did this, cca started working.